# rCharts HighCharts dataLabels

Tags: r, rcharts

I am using the following code to produce a scatterplot using rCharts & HighCharts.  I each point to have a their corresponding Ticker right next to the point at all times.  I would also like for the color of the dot to  be determined by "Type", and all points to be circles.

```
library(rCharts)

x <- as.data.frame(c(1:6))
x$Tickers <- c("DBC", "IWV", "TIP", "TLT", "SPY", "MODEL")
x$Return <- c(0, 15, 4.3, 7.3, 15, 7)
x$StdDev <- c(16, 16, 6, 15, 16, 6)
x$Type <- c('Asset', 'Asset', 'Asset', 'Asset', 'Benchmark', 'Model')
x


b <- hPlot(x="StdDev", y="Return", data = x, group="Type", type = "scatter")
b
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As is, the nodes are colored by "Type", you can force the nodes to be circles with this:

```
b$plotOptions(scatter=list(marker=list(symbol='circle')))
```